# Create a list of objects and display them in the console through another class

Tags: c#, list

For a homework assignment i need to create a `List<T>`, add objects to it, and display the objects toString. Here is what i have:

```
public class Order
{
    ...
      public List<OrderLine> orderLines;
      public Order(User user1)
      {
          ...
          orderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
      }

      public void AddOrderLine(OrderLine newOrderLine)
      {
          orderLines.Add(newOrderLine);
      }
}

public class OrderLine
{
   public OrderLine(Product p1, int q1)
   {
      ...
   }
   public override string ToString() //Required by teacher
   {
      string myOrderLine;
      myOrderLine = String.Format("[Product name: {0}; Price: {1}; Quantity: {2}]", 
         product.name, product.price, quantity);
      return myOrderLine;
   }
}
```

When adding oerderLines.Add(newOrderLine) new OrderLine is an object created in another class that has a working toString. How do i display all the newOrderLines from the Program.CS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your main method looks something like this:

```
{    
   User user = new User();    
   Order order = new Order(user);   
   OrderLine orderLine1 = new OrderLine();   
   order.AddOrderLine(orderLine1); 
}
```

If I understand what you say correctly, OrderLine already overrides ToString(), so that when you call ToString(), it returns something "human-meaningful". In that case, the only thing you need to do is something along the lines of

```
foreach (var orderLine in order.orderLines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(orderLine.ToString());
}
```

Note that it is considered good practice not to publicly expose a field, like orderLines. Better make it private, and create a public property like:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderLine> OrderLines
{
   get { return this.orderLines; }
}
```

Comment: You are right on with the main method, however the for each doesnt work. I will try looking into the IEnumerable.. new to this and havent heard of it yet. Thanks!

Comment: Do i make that public property in the Program.CS or the Order.CS?

Comment: In the Order.cs. The Order is responsible for providing a list of OrderLines to its consumers via its public property. It is backed up by a private field, which no one else should know about. That way, you can keep the public API the same (the public property), but reorganize the "internals" of Order whichever way you see fit.

Comment: The foreach should work; did you put in in the Main method of the Console app?

Comment: You don't have to use IEnumerable, you could also return List. The reason I did it is that IEnumerable is more general; a List promises to the user that items are in a certain order, and that you can Add or Remove. IEnumerable simply promises that items can be iterated over. That way, the public interface is less specific, you make a "narrow" promise to other classes that would use Order, and you have potentially less features to support over time (i.e. less potential bugs!).

Comment: Ya i had it in the main method. Not sure what i changed but i got it to work with the IEnumerable. Thanks so much for the help. I spent so much time trying to figure this out! Got a lot of learning to do... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the working `.ToString()` for the OrderLine class. If you just want to display them to the console, you can do a simple:

```
foreach(OrderLine orderline in orderLines)
   System.Console.WriteLine(orderline.ToString());
```

**edit:**

Two simple ways to do this is either the way Mathias outlined quite nicely or put my code inside your `Order` class. For example, add a new method like this:

```
public void PrintOrders()
{
    foreach(OrderLine orderline in this.orderLines)
       System.Console.WriteLine(orderline.ToString());  
}
```

You would use it like:

```
User user = new User();    
Order order = new Order(user);   
OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();
order.AddOrderLine(orderLine);
order.PrintOrders();
```

Please note that it is generally not considered good practice to have classes printing to the console. I just wanted to show you a different way of approaching the problem.

Comment: orderLines does not exist in current context ( for the in orderLines)

Comment: @Troy, orderLines exists inside the `Order` class. So either you'll have to use `orderObj.orderLines` inside the main program.cs file (or similar location) or put my code inside the `Order` class. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Order order = new Order();

    OrderLine line1 = new OrderLine(...);
    OrderLine line2 = new OrderLine(...);
    OrderLine line3 = new OrderLine(...);

    order.AddOrderLine(line1);
    order.AddOrderLine(line2);
    order.AddOrderLine(line3);

    foreach (OrderLine line in order.orderLines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that. Gives me "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication1.Order.orderLines'

Answer (score 0):

if you have something like this in your Program.cs to populate your Order object

```
var order = new Order();
order.AddOrderLine(...);

//this is how you can display each item ToString in the collection
foreach(var o in order.orderLines)
{
   Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
}
```

just check for any typo or syntax error as I only typed this here inline